# Making multiple Axios requests causing CORS errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, axios

I have a HTTP POST request I'm making from the frontend using `Axios` to the Firebase Functions backend.  I want to be able to send two requests at the same time to call two functions, `createEmaileList` and `zohoCrmHook`.  The problem is, when I make a request to both functions at the same time, it gives me the CORS error.  When I make a request to individual function, they work perfectly fine.  How do I make a request to multiple functions at the same time?

Following is the frontend:

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
    setLoading(true)                
    e.preventDefault()  
    axios.all([
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createEmailList`, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        }),
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/zohoCrmHook`, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        })
    ])
    .then(axios.spread((emailRes, crmRes) => { 
        if(emailRes.status===200 || emailRes.status===204 || crmRes.status===200 || crmRes.status===204 || crmRes.status===201){
            setLoading(false)
            closeModal()
        } 
    }))
    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
}
```

The backend `index.js` is as follows:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");
const createEmailList = require('./createEmailList')
const zohoCrmHook = require('./zohoCrmHook')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://landing-page.firebaseio.com"
})

exports.zohoCrmHook = functions.https.onRequest(zohoCrmHook)
exports.createEmailList = functions.https.onRequest(createEmailList)
```

I've imported the `cors` module and implemented the function as following, but it still only works individually and not both at the same time

createEmailList.js

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        if (!req.body.email) {
            return res.status(422).send({ error: 'Bad Input'})
        }

        const email = String(req.body.email)
        const firstName = String(req.body.firstName)
        const lastName = String(req.body.lastName)

        const data = {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName    
        }

        const db = admin.firestore()
        const docRef = db.collection('users')
            .doc(email)
            .set(data, { merge: false })
            .catch(err => res.status(422).send({ error: err }))

        return res.status(204).end();    
    })
}
```

zohoCrmHook.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

// zoho
const clientId = functions.config().zoho.client_id;
const clientSecret = functions.config().zoho.client_secret;
const refreshToken = functions.config().zoho.refresh_token;
const baseURL = 'https://accounts.zoho.com';

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, async () => {        
        const newLead = {
            'data': [
            {
                'Email': String(req.body.email),
                'Last_Name': String(req.body.lastName),
                'First_Name': String(req.body.firstName),
            }
            ],
            'trigger': [
                'approval',
                'workflow',
                'blueprint'
            ]
        };

        const { data } = await getAccessToken();
        const accessToken = data.access_token;

        const leads = await getLeads(accessToken);
        const result = checkLeads(leads.data.data, newLead.data[0].Email);

        if (result.length < 1) {
            try {
                return res.json(await createLead(accessToken, newLead));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("createLead error", e);
            }
        } else {
            return res.json({ message: 'Lead already in CRM' })
        }
    })
}
```

**Update**
I've also tried combining the two Firebase Functions into one as following:

```js
exports.myWebHook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  createEmailList(req, res)
  zohoCrmHook(req, res)
})
```

and converting the frontend `axios` request into one:

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
        setLoading(true)                
        e.preventDefault()  

        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/myWebHook`, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        })
        .then(res => { 
            if(res.status===200 || res.status===204){
                setLoading(false)
                closeModal()
            } 
        })
        .catch(err=> console.log(err));
    }
```

But, it still gives the same CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://us-landing-page.cloudfunctions.net/myWebHook'
>   from origin 'https://www.website.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

**Update2**
I've tried to incorporating the CORS module in `index.js` as following and removed the CORS module from both of the functions.

```js
exports.myWebHook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {            
    zohoCrmHook(req, res)  
    createEmailList(req, res)
  })
})
```

Now, the `axios` request to the server doesn't incur any CORS errors and the `myWebHook` function gets invoked with no issues, but the neither of `zohoCrmHook` nor `createEmailList` function gets invoked.

Comment: No idea about Firebase actually but importing CORS twice and setting its value looks suspicious. I have the feeling CORS should be initialized once and then only resources should be added. I know of an issue where setting multiple CORS headers in your stack throws errors. Not sure if that is exactly the case here but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: If I were to remove the CORS module from any one of the functions, the error that says the process has been blocked by the CORS policy simply points to that specific function.

Comment: thats sound better can you not set cors in your entry point and import your functions and add them as resources to the same cors instance?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and updated by answer, but still a no go

Comment: Actually, the server was delayed and now I'm seeing both functions being invoked properly. If you want to write your answer as a post, I'll give you the props. And thank you!

Comment: Was just a wild guess but thanks :)

Comment: When I was trying out different variations of applying the CORS module, I also got an error at one point saying that the Header that's been already been declared cannot be declared again. Didn't know what that meant at the time, but, looking at your answer, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the code we see that CORS in not only imported but also invoked with an options object. So I think it is instantiating CORS twice and setting multiple times the same CORS headers, which is known to cause issues.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
```

My suggestion is, to instantiate CORS once in the entry point and add the functions as resources to the same CORS instance.